# How to set default values to extended model in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, mezzanine

In a [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/) project, I have defined a simple `Photo` model that extends the core `Page` model:

```
from django.db import models
from mezzanine.pages.models import Page

class Photo(Page):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos")
    #publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True) #problematic
```

When I tried to re-define the `publish_date` field, I got error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'publish_date' in class 'Photo' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'Page'
```

I want to avoid filling `publish_date` in admin page each time I create a photo. So wondering how should I set it it to `now()` without touching the original `Page` model?

Comment: Good question. You definitely can't redefine the field. Hopefully you won't need to mess with the metaclass system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the definition of a field in a derived class of a model -- what if the base class relies on the existing behavior in any way?

What I'd suggest is define a custom save() method in your Photo class that adds the date, then calls the super() save:

```
import datetime
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        # instance is being created.
        self.publish_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you could create a mixin that adds this functionality to any class.